# Where is the definition of _TP_POOL structure?

Tags: c, windows, delphi, winapi, header-files

In order to translate windows vista thread pool API to use in my delphi application. I need to know the definition of `_TP_POOL`. I looked into `winnt.h` and found the following `typedef` declaration:

```
typedef struct _TP_POOL TP_POOL, *PTP_POOL;
```

I can't find the `_TP_POOL` on my local header files. Which is the location of it?

Comment: I will add Delphi tag, maybe another delphi programmer did this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PTP_POOL` is an opaque pointer. You never get to know, or indeed need to know, what that pointer refers to. The thread pool API serves up `PTP_POOL` values when you call `CreateThreadpool`. And you then pass those opaque pointer values back to the other thread pool API functions that you call. The thread pool API implementation knows what the pointer refers to, but you simply do not need to.

In Delphi I would declare it like this:

```
type
  PTP_POOL = type Pointer;
```

I'm declaring this as a distinct type so that the compiler will ensure that you don't assign pointers to other types to variables of type `PTP_POOL`.

Comment: Thank you David. You was very helpful, as usual.

Comment: Just for future reference and to be clear about this subject, how could I identify an opaque pointer like this?

Comment: Because the header file would never complete the struct definition.

Answer (score 3):

`_TP_POOL` is an incomplete type, which is never completed in the public headers.

This is a common C and C++ idiom for type-safe opaque handles.
In other words, they are used to completely hide the implementation.

The probably best-known example is `FILE`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not defined.  But given that TP_POOL is always passed around via pointer (PTP_POOL), you don't need to know its exact internals.  Just treat PTP_POOL as if was declared as a VOID* reference.

Comment: Thank you selbie. I was wondering that, but as I am not fluent in C/C++ I prefer asking as taking the risk of declaring as a pointer.